# Relative path on Web.Config (Azure WebAPI)

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, isapi

I'm trying to add an ISAPI filter to an Azure WebApp project. I tried following the official guidance here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/) but it didnt work for me.

I'm getting the following error:

**HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error**

Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "~/bin/ResponseFilter.dll" failed

What is the right way to specify relative dll path in web.config?

It is currently:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <isapiFilters>
      <filter name="ResponseFilter" path="~/bin/ResponseFilter.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />      
    </isapiFilters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try:

1) Use Kudu debugging console to understand the state of your deployment and where is that ResponseFilter at all. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console is the tutorial.

2) Detect your library

3) Test the config. Maybe it makes sense to put your filter file somewhere in the file system (can be implemented using the same console) and use the absolute path.

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Path for a filter must be the absolute physical path.
In azure web app, it'll likely be "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\ResponseFilter.dll"
[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690688(v=vs.90).aspx#Attributes%20and%20Elements)